# Update of element's priority in PriorityQueue is not taken into account

Tags: python, indexing, pass-by-reference, priority-queue

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

pq = PriorityQueue()
x = [20,0]
y = [20,0]
pq.put(x)
pq.put(y)
y[1] = -1
print(x,y) 
while not pq.empty():
    print(pq.get())
```

The output of the above program is:

```
[20,0]
[20,-1]
```

Where as the output should be in ascending order:

```
[20,-1]
[20,0]
```

Comment: It seems the output is just in reverse order?

Comment: I think the value of the y[1] is not updated in the priorityQueue and it is performing the heapify on the old values. Since y is the reference to the list, the change should also happen in the pq

Comment: But you do get [20, -1] out of the queue.

Comment: Yes, that's my doubt why is it happening and what can I do to prevent it

Comment: If you want to prevent getting [20,-1] out of the queue then either don't put y in the queue or don't set y[1] to -1.

Comment: Lol, thanks for the suggestion, but I need to update the value of y[1]

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are asking. Obviously, if you set y[1] to -1, y will be [20,-1] afterwards.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/priority-queue-set-1-introduction/ 
I want to get the item based on the priority

Comment: The title of your question has lead to some confusion, as the comments show: *"list value is not updating"*: it *is* updating, but your point is that the queue does not take the changed priority into account.

Comment: My bad, Thanks for pointing it out @trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mutating the pair after it has been put in the queue, you bypass the priority queue's logic. It is not notified about the update you made.

If you really have to modify the priority of an element that is already in the queue, then first invalidate it, and add a new element to it that is intended as replacement:

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

inf = float("inf")
pq = PriorityQueue()
x = [20,0]
y = [20,0]
pq.put(x)
pq.put(y)

# create a copy that has the desired modification
newy = [y[0], -1]
pq.put(newy)
# invalidate the element that was already in the queue
y[0] = -inf 
y[1] = -inf

while not pq.empty():
    val = pq.get()
    # ignore invalidated entries
    if val[0] != -inf:
        print(val)
```

Another approach would be to use `heapq` instead of `queue.PriorityQueue`, mutate the element and then call `heapify` to restore the heap property.

```
from heapq import heapify, heappush, heappop

heap = []
x = [20,0]
y = [20,0]
heappush(heap, x)
heappush(heap, y)

# mutate...
y[1] = -1
# ...and heapify
heapify(heap)

while heap:
    print(heappop(heap))
```

This looks simpler, but be aware that `heapify` has a linear time complexity: it visits all elements of the heap.